# ADF Integration Runtime - Limit Concurrent Jobs

Tags: azure-data-factory

We developed a pipeline with get meta data and for each activity. Inside for each, there are few activities like lookup, stored procedure, and delete.

Source is a file share. We have tried it with 5000 files, each file size is 3kb, using self hosted IR and concurrent jobs as 12. The time it took is 3hr 30min.

Will there be any improvement if we can increase concurrent jobs or it will just limit the concurrent jobs. Also please let me know what is the maximum limit of concurrent jobs.

Answer (score 0):

The default value of the concurrent jobs limit is set based on the machine size. The factors used to calculate this value depend on the amount of RAM and the number of CPU cores of the machine. So the more cores and the more memory, the higher the default limit of concurrent jobs.

You scale out by increasing the number of nodes. When you increase the number of nodes, the concurrent jobs limit is the sum of the concurrent job limit values of all the available nodes. For example, if one node lets you run a maximum of twelve concurrent jobs, then adding three more similar nodes lets you run a maximum of 48 concurrent jobs (that is, 4 x 12).